# Rails 3: Errno::ENOENT exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, path, temporary-files, fileutils

I have the code as following. It runs OK on my local machine

```
`params[:file].each do |f|
    tmp = f.tempfile
    ext = File.extname(f.original_filename)

    basic_file_name = "#{session[:user]["id"]}_#{Time.new.to_i}#{ext}".downcase

    file = File.join(TEMPORARY_FILE_FOLDER, basic_file_name)
    FileUtils.cp tmp.path, file`
```

But on my remote server which is a CentOS server, it gives me this

```
`Errno::ENOENT in CustomController#process_custom_order

No such file or directory - public/uploaded/709_1388758536.jpg`
```

Thanks, guys!

Comment: Sorry, first time post. The original code does not include those backquotes.

Comment: It seems the tempfile isn't working. Dont know how to fix it :(

Comment: Or it might be that I dont have access right to the /tmp folder